# Adding a new form when a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a calculator that takes several times inputed by the user, with the number of times being up to the user. I'd like to have a new form appear when a button is clicked.

I have tried to create on onclick event within the button, however nothing is happening when this is clicked.

See below relevant code

```js
 
let addButton = function() {
    let mile2Form = document.createElement('input');
    mile2Form.setAttribute('type', 'time');
    document.body.appendChild(mile2Form);
}
```

```html
<section>
    <button class= "addButton" onclick="addButton()">Add Another Time</button>
</section>
```

I expect for a new form to be created.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: The button successfully adds a new text input each time it's clicked. When you say "add a new form," do you mean add a new button also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create `createElement("form");` and add your control to form `form.appendChild(mile2Form);`

Also a good convention, you should move the script block before `</body>` tag

```
let addButton = function() {

var form = document.createElement("form");
form.setAttribute('method',"post");
form.setAttribute('action',"#");

    let mile2Form = document.createElement('input');

    mile2Form.setAttribute('type', 'time');

    form.appendChild(mile2Form);
    document.body.appendChild(form);
}
```

```js
let addButton = function() {

var form = document.createElement("form");
form.setAttribute('method',"post");
form.setAttribute('action',"#");

    let mile2Form = document.createElement('input');

    mile2Form.setAttribute('type', 'time');
    
    form.appendChild(mile2Form);
    document.body.appendChild(form);
}
```

```html
<section>

<button class= "addButton" onclick="addButton()">Add Another Time</button>
</section>
```

Comment: Many thanks for this. What would the ID of the new forms be? Would they all be unique or would each new form that is created have the same ID?

Comment: You should create unique id for each form, but you can set same class for forms